# How to change the desktop background with Powershell consistently

Tags: powershell

I am trying to change the desktop background with Powershell.
I had been trying to use the following code which only works some of the time.

```
Remove-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop" -name WallPaper -Force
Set-ItemProperty -path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\' -name Wallpaper -value $wallpaper -Force
RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters ,1 ,True
```

I had tried a number of other variations on this code like adding delays with Start-Sleep or using Start-Job {RUNDLL32.EXE ...} then Wait-Job.

I am guessing it is some sort of weirdness with trying to use RUNDLL32.exe.
I am running Windows 7 32bit with Powershell V5.

Curious side note, I run the same code in Powershell V6  on the same computer and the code runs flawlessly every time.
Any idea as to why that might be and how I might be able to get it to work consistently on Powershell V5?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [SystemParametersInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa) function of user32.dll like this:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class Wallpaper {
    public const uint SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x0014;
    public const uint SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
    public const uint SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int SystemParametersInfo (uint uAction, uint uParam, string lpvParam, uint fuWinIni);
    public static void SetWallpaper (string path) {
        SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, path, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
    }
}
'@


$wallpaper = 'X:\pictures\mywallpaper.jpg'  # absolute path to the image file
[Wallpaper]::SetWallpaper($wallpaper)
```